# R: Convert correlation matrix to edge list

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I want to create a network graph of my data, where the weight of the edges is defined by the correlation coefficient in a correlation matrix. The connection is defined by being statistically significant or not.

Since I want to play around with some parameters I need to have this information in an edge list rather than in matrix form, but I'm struggling as to how to convert this. I have tried to used `igraph` as shown below, but I cannot figure out how to get the information on which correlations are significant and which are not into the edge list. I guess weight could be set to zero to code that info, but how do I combine a correlation matrix and a p-value matrix?

```
library(igraph)
g  <- graph.adjacency(a,weighted=TRUE)
df <- get.data.frame(g)
df
```

Comment: Edited tags for better findability

Answer (score 2):

It'd be great if you could provide a minimal reproducable example, but I think I understand what you're asking for. You'll need to make a graph from a matrix using `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`, but make sure to input something in the `weighted` parameter, because otherwise the elements in the matrix represent number of edges (less than 1 means no edges). Then you can create an edge list from the graph using `as_data_frame`. Then perform whatever calculation you want, or join any external data you have, then you can convert it back to a graph by using `graph_from_data_frame`

```
cor_mat <- cor(mtcars)
cor_g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cor_mat, mode='undirected', weighted = 'correlation')
cor_edge_list <- as_data_frame(cor_g, 'edges')
only_sig <- cor_edge_list[abs(cor_edge_list$correlation) > .75, ]
new_g <- graph_from_data_frame(only_sig, F)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who still need this, here is the answer

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph.adjacency(a, mode="upper", weighted=TRUE, diag=FALSE)
e <- get.edgelist(g)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(e,E(g)$weight))
```